# Speeding up simulations

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, random-walk

I have the following situation:

A variable moves +1 with prob=0.5 and -1 with prob=-0.5 ... if this Markov Chain starts at position=5

- Situation 1: What is the expected time at which the variable will first reach position = 0?
- Situation 2: What is the expected time at which the variable will first reach position= 0 AFTER having gone to position=10 at least once?

I tried to do this as follows (I created a tracking variable to see where the simulation gets stuck):

```
# the simulations can take a long time to run, I interrupted them

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

n_sims <- 100
times_to_end_0 <- numeric(n_sims)
times_to_end_0_after_10 <- numeric(n_sims)
paths_0 <- vector("list", n_sims)
paths_0_after_10 <- vector("list", n_sims)

for (i in 1:n_sims) {
    print(paste("Running simulation", i, "for situation 1..."))
    y <- 5
    time <- 0
    path_0 <- c(y)

    while(y > 0) {
        step <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
        y <- y + step
        path_0 <- c(path_0, y)
        time <- time + 1

        if (y == 0) {
            times_to_end_0[i] <- time
            paths_0[[i]] <- data.frame(time = 1:length(path_0), y = path_0, sim = i)
            break
        }
    }

    print(paste("Running simulation", i, "for situation 2..."))
    y <- 5
    time <- 0
    reached_10 <- FALSE
    path_0_after_10 <- c(y)

    while(y > 0 || !reached_10) {
        step <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
        y <- y + step
        path_0_after_10 <- c(path_0_after_10, y)
        time <- time + 1

        if (y == 10) {
            reached_10 <- TRUE
        }

        if (y == 0 && reached_10) {
            times_to_end_0_after_10[i] <- time
            paths_0_after_10[[i]] <- data.frame(time = 1:length(path_0_after_10), y = path_0_after_10, sim = i)
            break
        }
    }
}

df1 <- data.frame(time = times_to_end_0)
df2 <- data.frame(time = times_to_end_0_after_10[times_to_end_0_after_10 > 0])

mean1 <- mean(log(df1$time))
mean2 <- mean(log(df2$time))

p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = log(time))) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = exp(mean1)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
    labs(title = paste("Density of Times to Reach 0 - Mean Time:", round(exp(mean1), 2)), x = "Time", y = "Density") + theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = log(time))) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = exp(mean2)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
    labs(title = paste("Density of Times to Reach 0 After Reaching 10 - Mean Time:", round(exp(mean2), 2)), x = "Time", y = "Density") + theme_bw() 

plot_df_0 <- do.call(rbind, paths_0)

p3 <- ggplot(plot_df_0, aes(x = log(time), y = y, group = sim)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = "Paths of First Simulation", x = "Time", y = "Y") +
    theme_bw()

plot_df_0_after_10 <- do.call(rbind, paths_0_after_10)

p4 <- ggplot(plot_df_0_after_10, aes(x = log(time), y = y, group = sim)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = "Paths of Second Simulation", x = "Time", y = "Y") +
    theme_bw()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

**My Question:** Is there anything I can do to improve the efficiency of this simulation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `sample()` in each cycle of your for/while loop creates a lot of overhead
and causes your simulations to run slow.

The solution below runs `sample()` once per simulation with a size of `1e6` (1,000,000).
You could also go bigger, `1e7` seems reasonably fast on my machine and all cycles
have hit `0` for several runs with `1e7`. At `1e8` things get slow and
at `1e9` is likely too much for most machines. The smaller you set the sample size
the more runs that don’t hit `0` you’ll get.

## Function

This function relies on vectorization to speed things up.

```r
sim <- function(y = 5,
                size = 1e6) {
  steps <- sample(c(-1, 1),
                  size,
                  prob = c(0.5, 0.5),
                  replace = TRUE)
  y_steps <- c(y, steps)
  y_steps_cum <- cumsum(y_steps)
  times <- which(y_steps_cum == 0)
  times_to_0 <- times[1]
  path <- if (!is.na(times_to_0))
    y_steps_cum[1:times_to_0]
  else
    NA
  touched_10 <- which(y_steps_cum == 10)[1]
  times_to_0_after_10 <-
    if (!is.na(touched_10))
      times[times > touched_10][1]
  else
    NA
  path_to_0_after_10 <-
    if (!is.na(times_to_0_after_10))
      y_steps_cum[1:times_to_0_after_10]
  else
    NA
  
  list(
    times_to_0 = times_to_0,
    path = list(path),
    touched_10 = touched_10,
    times_to_0_after_10 = times_to_0_after_10,
    path_to_0_after_10 = list(path_to_0_after_10)
  )
}
```

A single simulation:

```r
sim()
#> $times_to_0
#> [1] 314
#> 
#> $path
#> $path[[1]]
#>   [1]  5  4  3  2  3  4  3  4  3  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7
#>  [26]  6  7  6  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10 11 12 11 12 11 12 13 12 11 12 13 12
#>  [51] 13 12 11 12 11 10 11 10 11 10 11 12 13 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  7
#>  [76]  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  9  8  7  8  7  6  7  8  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4
#> [101]  3  4  5  6  5  6  5  6  7  8  7  8  7  6  7  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  9  8  9
#> [126]  8  7  6  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  9  8  9  8  9 10
#> [151] 11 12 11 12 11 10 11 10 11 12 11 12 13 12 13 14 15 16 15 14 15 14 13 12 13
#> [176] 14 15 14 15 16 17 18 19 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 11 10  9 10
#> [201]  9 10 11 12 11 10 11 10  9 10 11 10 11 12 13 12 13 14 15 14 15 16 17 16 15
#> [226] 14 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  9  8  7  8  9 10 11 10 11 12 11 10 11 10  9 10
#> [251]  9 10 11 12 11 12 11 10  9 10 11 12 11 12 13 12 11 12 13 12 13 14 13 12 13
#> [276] 12 11 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  7  8  7  6  7  6  5  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  3  4
#> [301]  5  4  5  4  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0
#> 
#> 
#> $touched_10
#> [1] 20
#> 
#> $times_to_0_after_10
#> [1] 314
#> 
#> $path_to_0_after_10
#> $path_to_0_after_10[[1]]
#>   [1]  5  4  3  2  3  4  3  4  3  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7
#>  [26]  6  7  6  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10 11 12 11 12 11 12 13 12 11 12 13 12
#>  [51] 13 12 11 12 11 10 11 10 11 10 11 12 13 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  7
#>  [76]  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  9  8  7  8  7  6  7  8  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4
#> [101]  3  4  5  6  5  6  5  6  7  8  7  8  7  6  7  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  9  8  9
#> [126]  8  7  6  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  9  8  9  8  9 10
#> [151] 11 12 11 12 11 10 11 10 11 12 11 12 13 12 13 14 15 16 15 14 15 14 13 12 13
#> [176] 14 15 14 15 16 17 18 19 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 11 10  9 10
#> [201]  9 10 11 12 11 10 11 10  9 10 11 10 11 12 13 12 13 14 15 14 15 16 17 16 15
#> [226] 14 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  9  8  7  8  9 10 11 10 11 12 11 10 11 10  9 10
#> [251]  9 10 11 12 11 12 11 10  9 10 11 12 11 12 13 12 11 12 13 12 13 14 13 12 13
#> [276] 12 11 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  7  8  7  6  7  6  5  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  3  4
#> [301]  5  4  5  4  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0
```

100 simulations:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tictoc::tic() # tic() and toc() are for benchmarking

res <-
  lapply(rep(5, 100),
         sim) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "sim")

tictoc::toc()
#> 2.596 sec elapsed

res
#> # A tibble: 100 × 6
#>    sim   times_to_0 path       touched_10 times_to_0_after_10 path_to_0_after_10
#>    <chr>      <int> <list>          <int>               <int> <list>            
#>  1 1           3202 <dbl>              26                3202 <dbl [3,202]>     
#>  2 2           1690 <dbl>              16                1690 <dbl [1,690]>     
#>  3 3             32 <dbl [32]>      11586               12012 <dbl [12,012]>    
#>  4 4            386 <dbl>              54                 386 <dbl [386]>       
#>  5 5            280 <dbl>              20                 280 <dbl [280]>       
#>  6 6             20 <dbl [20]>        272                2890 <dbl [2,890]>     
#>  7 7           3520 <dbl>              20                3520 <dbl [3,520]>     
#>  8 8            160 <dbl>               8                 160 <dbl [160]>       
#>  9 9         141814 <dbl>               8              141814 <dbl [141,814]>   
#> 10 10          1474 <dbl>              10                1474 <dbl [1,474]>     
#> # ℹ 90 more rows
```

## Plotting Results

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gridExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     combine

mean1 <- mean(log(res$times_to_0), na.rm = TRUE)
mean2 <- mean(log(res$times_to_0_after_10), na.rm = TRUE)

p1 <-
  ggplot(res, aes(x = log(times_to_0))) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = exp(mean1)),
             color = "red",
             linetype = "dotted") +
  labs(
    title = paste("Density of Times to Reach 0 - Mean Time:", round(exp(mean1), 2)),
    x = "Time",
    y = "Density"
  ) + theme_bw()

p2 <- 
  ggplot(res, aes(x = log(times_to_0_after_10))) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = exp(mean2)),
             color = "red",
             linetype = "dotted") +
  labs(
    title = paste(
      "Density of Times to Reach 0 After Reaching 10 - Mean Time:",
      round(exp(mean2), 2)
    ),
    x = "Time",
    y = "Density"
  ) + theme_bw()

p3 <-
  res |>
  select(sim, path) |>
  unnest(path) |>
  mutate(time = 1:n(), .by = sim) |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = log(time),
    y = path,
    group = sim
  )) +
  geom_line(linewidth = .05) +
  labs(title = "Paths of First Simulation", x = "Time", y = "Y") +
  theme_bw()

p4 <-
  res |>
  select(sim, path_to_0_after_10) |>
  unnest(path_to_0_after_10) |>
  mutate(time = 1:n(), .by = sim) |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = log(time),
    y = path_to_0_after_10,
    group = sim
  )) +
  geom_line(linewidth = .05) +
  labs(title = "Paths of Second Simulation", x = "Time", y = "Y") +
  theme_bw()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`).
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 row containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[image]

Comment: @ Till: thank you so much for this wonderful answer!

Answer (score 10):

It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306467/expected-number-of-steps-for-reaching-k-in-a-random-walk) that the expected time to move from `k` to `k + 1` in a symmetric random walk is infinite. We can still simulate right-censored walk times.

Below is a more direct approach to the simulation. Think about moving from 5 to 6. It will always take an odd number of steps. The [probability](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/312/RW.pdf) of it taking `2*n - 1` steps is `abs(choose(0.5, n))`. Once it reaches 6, the number of steps to go from 6 to 7 is independent of the number of steps it took to go from 5 to 6.

To speed up the simulation, first pre-calculate the CDF of the number of steps to move 1 space. If we want to simulate how many steps it takes to move `n` spaces total, we can sum `n` random samples from the pre-calculated CDF. (The distribution is very heavy tailed, so we will let it run up to a maximum number of steps, at which the simulation will be terminated early and return `Inf`.)

Implementing the simulation as a function:

```
max.steps <- 1e8 + 1
p <- c(0, cumsum(abs(choose(0.5, 1:((max.steps + 1)/2)))), 1)

f <- function(n, path) {
  m <- matrix(2*findInterval(runif(sum(abs(diff(path)))*n), p) - 1, n)
  m[m > max.steps] <- Inf
  rowSums(m)
}
```

Simulating situation 1:

```
# moving from 5 to 0
path <- c(5, 0)
f(10, path)
#>  [1]   21  189   25   15   19   31  137   25   43 1199
# probability of stopping the simulation early (steps = Inf)
1 - p[length(p) - 1]^sum(abs(diff(path)))
#> [1] 0.0003988786
```

Simulating situation 2:

```
path <- c(5, 10, 0)
f(10, path)
#>  [1]   34459      33     545     115     237     109     143   14287 1251545
#> [10]     613
# probability of stopping the simulation early (steps = Inf)
1 - p[length(p) - 1]^sum(abs(diff(path)))
#> [1] 0.001196159
```

The pre-calculations take some time, but they need only be computed once. And once they are complete, the simulation runs very fast:

```
# pre-calculation time
system.time(p <- c(0, cumsum(abs(choose(0.5, 1:((max.steps + 1)/2)))), 1))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   18.02    0.47   18.50
# time 1M simulation runs
system.time(f(1e6, c(5, 10, 0)))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.83    0.02    0.86
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, can you please show me how to visualize the results based on your code? thank you so much!

Comment: What kind of visualization are you looking for? The two questions posed in your post ask about expected time (steps) to reach certain points given a starting point. It is well known that the expected time to move from `k` to `k + 1` is infinite. The function in my answer will allow you to quickly simulate right-censored stopping times, but not the paths of the individual simulation runs. I'd suggest `hist(log(f(1e6, c(5, 10, 0))))`.

Comment: Is there something I can use to plot the paths of each individual simulation?

Comment: No. The speedup comes from skipping the individual steps and going straight to the total number of steps for each replication.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** Instead of simulation efforts, here is just some of my thoughts for your ***Situation 1***, in which I was trying to obtain an analytical solution for the mean value of times reaching `0` from `5`.

---

Assuming you have `u` times `+1` (where `u` should be any non-negative integer, and you need to have `u+5` times `-1` such that you can reach `0` from `5`.

In that sense, you have in total `u + u + 5 = 2u+5` steps, and thus the probability is

```
P(u) = (choose(2*u+4,u)-choose(2*u+4,u-1))*0.5^(2*u+5)
```

where `choose(2*u+4,u)-choose(2*u+4,u-1)` is the number of paths that don't hit `0` before that last step. ***For generalization, it can be formulated as `choose(2*u+K-1,u)-choose(2*u+K-1,u-1)` if there should be `u` times `+1` and `u+K` times `-1`, e.g., from start value `K` to first reaching `0`.***

Since `u` should be any non-negative integer, the expectation of times to reach `5` should be calculated like below

```
  sum_{u=0}^{Inf} (2*u+5)*P(u) 
= sum_{u=0}^{Inf} (2*u+5)*(choose(2*u+4,u)-choose(2*u+4,u-1))*0.5^(2*u+5)
```

however, the series sum shown above **diverges**, unfortunately.

---

Below is just an illustration example regarding the distribution

```
u <- 0:500
N <- 2 * u + 5
P <- (choose(N-1, u) - choose(N-1, u + 5)) * 0.5^(N)
plot(N, P)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Can your code be adapted to plot the individual simulation trajectories (i.e. paths)?

Comment: @stats_noob see another answer of mine.

Answer (score 4):

## For Situation 1

First of all, if you want to find all possible trajectories, I don't think it is efficient to capture all of them if you use **"simulations"** only, since the expanded space blows up when you have longer trajectories.

---

Appended to the question *"Can your code be adapted to plot the individual simulation trajectories (i.e. paths)?"* (see the comments to the answer by [@ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857128/12158757)), you can enumerate all that paths using the recursion manner.

## Code to Find All Trajettories

If you want to get all trajectories that departs from a source node `src` to the first-hit target `tg` with `L` hops, you can try the code below

```
f <- function(L, src, tg = 0) {
  # not available if number of hops shorter than the source-target distance
  if (L < abs(src - tg)) {
    return(list())
  }
  # there is one single path if number of hops equals to the distance
  if (L == abs(src-tg)) {
    return(list(src:tg))
  }
  if (L == 1) {
    if (src %in% (tg + c(1, -1))) {
      return(list(c(src, tg)))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  }
  # if next hop is "+1"
  if (src + 1 != tg) {
    u <- Recall(L - 1, src + 1, tg)
  } else {
    u <- NULL
  }
  # if next hop is "-1"
  if (src - 1 != tg) {
    v <- Recall(L - 1, src - 1, tg)
  } else {
    v <- NULL
  }
  # if u or v is not NULL, expand the paths with the source node
  ps <- c(u, v)
  if (!is.null(ps)) {
    Map(c, src, c(u, v))
  } else {
    list()
  }
}
```

## Output Examples

```
> f(5, 5)
[[1]]
[1] 5 4 3 2 1 0


> f(6, 5)
list()

> f(7, 5)
[[1]]
[1] 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 5 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[3]]
[1] 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0

[[4]]
[1] 5 4 3 2 3 2 1 0

[[5]]
[1] 5 4 3 2 1 2 1 0


> f(8, 5)
list()

> f(9, 5)
[[1]]
 [1] 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[2]]
 [1] 5 6 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[3]]
 [1] 5 6 5 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[4]]
 [1] 5 6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0

[[5]]
 [1] 5 6 5 4 3 2 3 2 1 0

[[6]]
 [1] 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 1 0

[[7]]
 [1] 5 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[8]]
 [1] 5 4 5 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[9]]
 [1] 5 4 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0

[[10]]
 [1] 5 4 5 4 3 2 3 2 1 0

[[11]]
 [1] 5 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 1 0

[[12]]
 [1] 5 4 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[13]]
 [1] 5 4 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 0

[[14]]
 [1] 5 4 3 4 3 2 3 2 1 0

[[15]]
 [1] 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 2 1 0

[[16]]
 [1] 5 4 3 2 3 4 3 2 1 0

[[17]]
 [1] 5 4 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 0

[[18]]
 [1] 5 4 3 2 3 2 1 2 1 0

[[19]]
 [1] 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 0

[[20]]
 [1] 5 4 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 0
```

## Trajectory Visualization

If you want to visualize all those trajectories

```
paths <- f(9, 5)
tryCatch(
  expr = {
    nr <- ceiling(sqrt(length(paths)))
    nc <- ceiling(length(paths) / nr)
    par(mfrow = c(nr, nc))
    invisible(lapply(paths, \(x) {
      plot(x, type = "b")
      grid()
    }))
  },
  error = function(e) {
    print("No valide paths found!")
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: @stats_noob you are welcome. I added some comments in the code and hope they can help you understand the recursion easier.

Answer (score 4):

## For Situation 2

A follow-up on top of the answer by [@ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77872272/12158757), here is the code to find all possible trajectories that pass a mid-point (see ***Situation 2*** in the question).

## Code

Let `L`, `src`, `mid`, and `tg` denote the total number of hops, source node, *first-hit* midpoint, and *first-hit* target, respectively, we can try the code to generate all paths but need to the

```
ff <- function(L, src, mid, tg) {
  l <- abs(src - mid):(L - abs(tg - mid))
  unlist(
    lapply(
      l,
      \(k) {
        p1 <- f(k, src, mid)
        p2 <- f(L - k, mid, tg)
        if (min(length(p1), length(p2)) > 0) {
          unlist(
            lapply(p1, \(x) Map(\(a, b) c(head(a, -1), b), list(x), p2)),
            recursive = FALSE
          )
        }
      }
    ),
    recursive = FALSE
  )
}
```

## Output Example

```
L <- 19
src <- 5
mid <- 10
tg <- 0
paths <- ff(L, src, mid, tg)
```

gives

```
> paths
[[1]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[2]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[3]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[4]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[5]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[6]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[7]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[8]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[9]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[10]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[11]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[12]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[13]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[14]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[15]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[16]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[17]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[18]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[19]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[20]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[21]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[22]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[23]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[24]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[25]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[26]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[27]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[28]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[29]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[30]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[31]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[32]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[33]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[34]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[35]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[36]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[37]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[38]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[39]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[40]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[41]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[42]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[43]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[44]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[45]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[46]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[47]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[48]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[49]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[50]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[51]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[52]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[53]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[54]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[55]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[56]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[57]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[58]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[59]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[60]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[61]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[62]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[63]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[64]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  2  1  0

[[65]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  2  1  0

[[66]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[67]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[68]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[69]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[70]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[71]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[72]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[73]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[74]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[75]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[76]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[77]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[78]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[79]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[80]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[81]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[82]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[83]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[84]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[85]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[86]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[87]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[88]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[89]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[90]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[91]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[92]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[93]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[94]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[95]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[96]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[97]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[98]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[99]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[100]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[101]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[102]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[103]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[104]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[105]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[106]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[107]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[108]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[109]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[110]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[111]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[112]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[113]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  4  3  2  1  0

[[114]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  3  2  1  0

[[115]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  1  0

[[116]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[117]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[118]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[119]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[120]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[121]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[122]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[123]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[124]]
 [1]  5  6  7  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[125]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[126]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[127]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[128]]
 [1]  5  6  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[129]]
 [1]  5  6  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[130]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[131]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  8  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[132]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  7  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[133]]
 [1]  5  4  5  6  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[134]]
 [1]  5  4  5  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

[[135]]
 [1]  5  4  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

## Trajectory Visualization

```
ps <- do.call(cbind, paths)
matplot(ps, type = "b")
grid()
```

shows

[image]