# R: Rotate a plot horizontally

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following "Tree" that depicts the results of a coin flipping game:

```
outcomes <- c(-1, 1)  

combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), 10))
colnames(combinations) <- paste("Turn", 1:10)

library(data.tree)

generate_tree <- function(node, depth, total) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        node$Set(total = total)
        return(node)
    } else {
        for (outcome in outcomes) {
            child <- node$AddChild(name = as.character(total + outcome), total = total + outcome)
            generate_tree(child, depth - 1, total + outcome)
        }
        return(node)
    }
}

root <- Node$new("Start", total = 5)

root <- generate_tree(root, 6, 5)

print(root, "total")

plot(root, "total")
```

[image]

**My Question:** Is it possible to rotate this tree horizontally?  I tried looking at different options but this does not seem possible using the data.tree library?  (it is possible in visnetwork and igraph however).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of rotating a `data.tree` plot is to convert it to a DiagrammeR object and edit that object manually with `gsub`.
Not nice but it works.
There should also be some way to make the rotated tree plot fill more of the plot area. The documentation of [`plot.Node`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/data.tree.pdf) (see also the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html)) suggests users to take a look at the documentation of the [`DiagrammeR`](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/) package.

```r
outcomes <- c(-1, 1)

combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), 10))
colnames(combinations) <- paste("Turn", 1:10)

library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

generate_tree <- function(node, depth, total) {
  if (depth == 0) {
    node$Set(total = total)
    return(node)
  } else {
    for (outcome in outcomes) {
      child <- node$AddChild(name = as.character(total + outcome), total = total + outcome)
      generate_tree(child, depth - 1, total + outcome)
    }
    return(node)
  }
}

root <- Node$new("Start", total = 5)
root <- generate_tree(root, 6, 5)

root %>%
  ToDiagrammeRGraph(direction = "descend") %>%
  generate_dot() %>%
  gsub(pattern = "\\{", "{\n\ngraph [rankdir = 'LR'];", x = ., perl = TRUE) %>%
  grViz()
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77829656/speeding-up-simulations thank you so much!